# Loop until data set is not in use with JCL

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

I am working in mainframe and I need to wait a dataset is released to execute automatically a JOB. Do you know any simple way to loop until a dataset is not in use in JCL? I was looking on the web and i found some solutions with REXX but they seemed too complicated to do such simple thing as I need. Also I have never used REXX.

Regards!

P.D. Also, the data set could not exist.

Edit: I need this becouse I run a XCOM Job which transfer a file of another system to a mainframe dataset. The problem is when this JOB finish, maybe the file is still beign transfered, and would like to wait to transfer be completed before to start the next JOB. Maybe editing the sentence of the next JOB associated to the dataset.

Comment: You can't loop with JCL, and you don't want to. Before you even remotely consider doing it in Rexx, please find out how it will impact the charging structure for the Mainframe you are using. Any Operations, Production Control or Support personnel will completely hate the idea, as will the cleaning staff. You do this by using a Scheduler, or by using the appropriate DISP for a dataset. If DISP=NEW/MOD/OLD then any other JOB using that dataset simply has to wait without you needing to do anything. It may seem a "simple" thing to do but, to be blunt, it is a bad thing to do on a Mainframe.

Comment: Hello @Bill Woodger, Maybe loop is not the word. The dataset is not used in a previous step. I will edit the question with more detail.

Comment: OK, clearer what you want. Answer is the same, but more targeted. Talk to you "Production Control" people. That's the people responsible for running the production systems (actual name may be different at your site). They will tell you how that type of thing is already done at your site, or they will come up with a way to do it. If you invent you own way, or try to pick one from the internet, it will surely be "bounced" before it gets anywhee close to Production.. Do it the way they want, which fits in with their Security and Audit procedures, implementation and execution standards, etc.

Comment: Late to the party here, but I wanted to add that many sites have a vendor product that does what you're talking about. The most popular is CA MIM (or whatever it's called these days)...if you try to use a dataset that's in use, your job is suspended and re-queued for execution. When the dataset becomes available, your job is automatically released and it runs without contention. This all happens much more efficiently than you could do it in JCL, REXX or any other conventional programming language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to ensure that your file transfer package allocates the dataset with an OLD disposition, that will create a system level enqueue on the dataset and prevent your job from running until the enqueue is released.

Many file transfer packages offer some sort of 'file complete' exit that can also trigger a job once a dataset transmission is fully complete.

But you can't loop in JCL.  You can in REXX, but it has a host of issues that you have to deal with, not at all simple.

Comment: Hello @Joe Zitzelberger. Does it work if the dataset is not even created yet?

Comment: @Nico OLD, NEW and MOD all require single use, as Joe has outliined. Obviously you can't use DISP=OLD on a dataset which does not exist yet, but NEW and MOD you can. I strongly suggest you read my last comment on your question. You're wasting time, despite Joe being correct.